# edit in place as described on jquery site not working

Tags: jquery

This is straight lift from [edit-in-place-using-ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Edit_in_Place_with_Ajax) but it is not working. can anyone suggest why?  neither save button nor cancel button does anything. I figured that saveButton and cancelButton when clicked are not firing the jquery code assigned to their click event.

```
<script src="/jscript/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#editInPlace").click(function(){
        var textarea = '<div><textarea rows="5" cols="30">' + $(this).html() + '</textarea>';
        var button = '<div><input type="button" value="SAVE" class="saveButton" /> OR <input type="button" value="CANCEL" class="cancelButton"/></div></div>';
        var revert = $(this).html();
        $(this).after(textarea+button).remove();
    });
    $('.saveButton').click(function(){saveChanges(this, false);});
    $('.cancelButton').click(function(){saveChanges(this, revert);});
    function saveChanges(obj, cancel) {
        if (!cancel) {
            var t = $(obj).parent().siblings(0).val();
            alert('new text='+t);
        }else {
            var t = revert;         //orig code had cancel;
            }
        $(obj).parent().parent().after('<div id="editInPlace">'+t+'</div>').remove()
    }

});
</script>



 <div id='editInPlace'>we are going to change this comment.</div>
```

adding images for @nbrook (based on his suggested code)....

initial display -> [image: initial_display]

on first click -> [image: on first click]

on second click inside textarea -> [image: on second click...]

this goes on...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to bind event handlers to elements that don't exist on page load. Change these:

```
$('.saveButton').click(function(){saveChanges(this, false);});
$('.cancelButton').click(function(){saveChanges(this, revert);});
```

to:

```
$('div#editInPlace').on('click', 'input.saveButton', function(){saveChanges(this, false);});
$('div#editInPlace').on('click', 'input.cancelButton', function(){saveChanges(this, revert);});
```

Comment: that didn't help. it is still not doing anything on clicking any button.

Comment: @rajeev Create a jsFiddle, please, and I'll see if I can track the problem down.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't seem to be a very good tutorial, even for basics. Pay careful attention to the scope of your variables: when you declare `var revert` within one `function() {}` wrapping, it will *not* be available in the outer scope or inside of other `function() {}` blocks, unless they are nested in the original one. Therefore, in all your other functions, `revert` doesn't exist. Referencing it causes a `ReferenceError`, and the JS interpreter breaks on all errors, so you won't get the alert. This should show up in your JS error console. Try this change:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var revert;

    $("#editInPlace").click( function() {
        var textarea = '<div><textarea rows="5" cols="30">' + $(this).html()
                     + '</textarea>';
        var button = '<div><input type="button" value="SAVE" class="saveButton" />'
                   + 'OR <input type="button" value="CANCEL" class="cancelButton"/>'
                   + '</div></div>';

        revert = $(this).html();

        //$(this).after(textarea+button).remove();

        // to have this work more than once, better to do (corresponding change below)
        $(this).html(textarea+button);
    });

    // use delegated event handler for dynamically generated elements
    $('#editInPlace').on( 'click', '.saveButton', function() {
        saveChanges(this, false);
        return false;
    })
    .on( 'click', '.editButton', function() {
        saveChanges(this, revert);
        return false;
    }) // (you could also combine these into a single handler, based on `this`)

    .on( 'click', 'textarea', function() {
        return false;
    });
});

// no need for this in ready handler
function saveChanges(obj, cancel) {
    if (!cancel) {
        var t = $(obj).parent().siblings(0).val();
        alert('new text='+t);
    } else {
        var t = cancel;  // use cancel, that's why you pass it in...revert not in scope
        ///var t = revert; // orig code had cancel;
    }

    // If you use the approach below, your div clicks will only work once
    //$(obj).parent().parent().after('<div id="editInPlace">'+t+'</div>').remove()

    // Instead, do:
    $(obj).closest('#editInPlace').html(t); // replace the current html with the old stuff
}
```

<del>Note I assume that you actually have the save and cancel buttons in your markup, and just chose not to include them in your post since they're not really relevant...</del>

**Correction:** Figured out where you were adding them...

Comment: after using your code. new issues are seen. every time i click inside the textarea, i get a new set of save/cancle button and text inside textarea. I am not able to edit inside textarea. i will upload images to main question.

Comment: works correctly now, except after the first set of SAVE or CANCEL is done. The div atgs inserted by the javascript code around the 'text' remains. so if you click on it agian, you see the div tags in the text to edit as : `<div>change this comment.</div>`

Comment: @rajeev Right, targeting the wrong parent in the last line. See my updated code. `$(obj).closest('#editInPlace').html(t);` -- should work fine now

Answer (score 0):

Hello Closing this question. I guess, it is too much to spend time on this. I have decided to use jeditable. It looks good and small enough to load on to browser.

thanks all for their help and time. Sorry I had to change route and pick jeditable library. It has more code and options than i want but, my tests with above code (and many changes) were producing this-or-that wrong effect.